# Community - English to Spanish

Tags: community, language, multi

The community pages are currently only available in English, including static pages, tabs, and images. The community platform itself does not support multiple languages. However, the client is now requesting a translation of the website into Spanish. When attempting to translate the website using browser extensions or other methods, the translated version appears blank due to the static nature of the content.

Is there a solution or workaround to translate the website into Spanish without making any changes to the community platform? Any assistance or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "static pages and images"?  Are you talking about hard-coded text content, and images that have words in them?  Please [edit] your post to clarify.  Also describe what research you have already done into Translation Workbench and other Salesforce translation features.

Comment: it is still not clear what you mean or what specific things you have tried.  If you need to translate the text content of your community pages, then you will need to supply the translated text yourself, and then probably use page variations for the Spanish version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom labels on the website and then provide a translation of these custom labels in Spanish.

You can create these custom labels in the English language. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cl_edit.htm&type=5

Then provide a translation of those custom labels
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cl_translate_edit.htm&type=5